# How to fix jenkins with chrome driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension

I am running Jenkins job for maven project. Chrome browser is not getting launched

I have tried updating Chrome browser to latest version and Chromedriver.exe. But still I have the following problem.

Error occurred while job is running. It is keep loading and throws this error.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90 dcaf7e3ec6f70a194cc25e8149475c6590e025-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1003}) on port 43963 Only local connections are allowed. Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Jun 19, 2019 10:23:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO: Detected dialect: W3C "
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Jun 19, 2019 10:23:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO: Detected dialect: W3C "

After this it says keep loading.

When i saw in task manager, chromedriver.exe and chrome.exe are running. But chrome browser is not opening.

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\java\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
  driver.manage().window().maximize();